# Separate coloring for each bar in a Stacked BarChart

Tags: color, charts

In a stacked bar chart, how do I give individual stacks separate colorings?

For example, how would I modify the following code

```
BarChart[{{4. 4, 0.7}, {3.5, 1.6, 1.2}}, ChartLayout->"Stacked"]
```

so each element in two stacks has its own color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like gwr's answer, but I thought it would be good to show how to do this with basic list manipulation.

```
data = {{4.4, 0.7}, {3.5, 1.6, 1.2}};
colors = {{Orange, LightBlue}, {Red, White, Blue}};
bars = MapThread[Style[#1, #2] & , #] & /@ Transpose[{data, colors}];
BarChart[bars, ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

[image: chart]

Comment: I will accept this solution since I like the primitive list manipulation functions and they have the best backward compatibility.

Comment: I think following will also work. `bars = Apply[Style,Transpose/@Transpose[{data,colors}],{2}]` but I don't know which one is more efficient?

Comment: @user13892. Don't worry about efficiency in this case as the lists are not likely to be very long. Go with the code that looks best to you for reasons of readability and maintainability. Efficiency only becomes important when the lists have lengths in thousands or greater.

Comment: @user13892 Do you really find `Apply[ Style, Transpose/@Transpose[{data,colors}],{2} ]` good to read and maintain? There is a reason for having named slots and for people not using Assembler these days. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

While I am not sure whether you can address individual bars in a *stacked* bar start with `ColorFunction` the immediate way to color individual bars is to use the `Style` wrapper:

```
BarChart[ 
   { (* Bar 1 *)
       { Style[ 4.4, color1 ] , Style[ 0.7, color2 ] }
   , (* Bar 2 *)
       { Style[ 3.5, color3], Style[ 1.6, color4 ], Style[1.2, color5] }
   }
   , ChartLayout->"Stacked"
]
```

Where `color1` to `color5` can be [color directives](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Colors.html). Note: This is actually all the OP asked for and it is indeed backward compatible down to Version 7, when `BarChart` was introduced.

To make this more convenient and to use modern data structures that make data more readable and thus maintainable:

```
$barData = Association @@@ {
    {
         "Height" -> {4.4, 0.7},
         "Color" -> {Red, Blue}
    }
    ,
    {
        "Height" -> {3.5, 1.6, 1.2},
        "Color" -> {Yellow, Green, Pink}
    }
};

$bars =  Query[All, {#Height, #Color} & /* MapThread[Style] ] @ $barData;

BarChart[ $bars, ChartLayout -> "Stacked" ]
```

[image: BarChart]

**EDIT**

To follow the example given by m_goldberg in his answer, I would like to show how `$barData` as an `Association` can be build from list data:

```
$heightData = {{4.4, 0.7}, {3.5, 1.6, 1.2}};
$colorData = {{Red, Blue}, {Yellow, Green, Pink}};

$barData = MapThread[
    AssociationThread[ { "Height", "Color" }, { ## } ]&,
    { $heightData, $colorData }
]
```

> {<|"Height" -> {4.4, 0.7},    "Color" -> {RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[
>       0, 0, 1]}|>, <|"Height" -> {3.5, 1.6, 1.2},    "Color" -> {RGBColor[1, 1, 0], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[
>       1, 0.5, 0.5]}|>}

Answer (score 6):

Using [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html), as long as the individual values are distinct, the colors will be distinct.

```
BarChart[{{4.4, 0.7}, {3.5, 1.6, 1.2}}, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 ColorFunction -> Function[{height}, ColorData["Rainbow"][height]]]
```

[image]

Or with a legend

```
Legended[
 BarChart[data = {{4.4, 0.7}, {3.5, 1.6, 1.2}}, 
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
  ColorFunction -> Function[{height}, ColorData["Rainbow"][height]]],
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", MinMax[data]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I was wandering how to do this with `ColorFunction` so the `ColorFunction` is taking the actual value of the bar. So if i put an association with <|value->color,...|> as my color function i will be able to explicitly define my colors? right.

Answer (score 4):

FWIF, `BarChart` gives the desired result if the style directives are passed as metadata:

```
data = {{4.4, 1.2}, {3.5, 1.6, 1.2}};
colors = {{Red, Blue}, {Orange, Green , Yellow}};

dm = Thread /@ Thread[data -> colors]
```

[image]

```
BarChart[dm, ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

[image]